# JUDDI ws doesn't start

Tags: tomcat, juddi

I downloaded JUDDI 3.2.0 and I have followed the guide to run it:
enter into the directory juddi_tomcat and start the preconfigured tomcat server.
The tomcat server starts but the ws juddiv3 doesn't.
The log says:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.juddi.webconsole.StartupServlet.contextInitialized(StartupServlet.java:50)
...
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:804)
...
```

Prerequisites just need a JRE, so I don't understand why it is not working. I have not specified another Log4JLogger anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need the JDK in order to run. Juddi has a number of JSP pages that are compiled at runtime. If the JRE was specified in the docs, and the JDK fixes it, please file a bug report so that we can track it and fix. That said, the error message doesn't appear to be JDK related, maybe an accidently deleted file?

Also, did you download the distribution or from source? In either case, I just downloaded the 3.2.0 release with JDK 7 installed and it started up just fine. We generally code for JDK6 or older. Often the best place for help is to ask the person(s) that made it (i.e. the juddi mailing list) or the issue tracker.